# Git advertisePushOptions config is already enabled but push options are not working. Am I missing something?

Tags: git

I have a bare git repository and would like to use push options.
Searching I found a command to enable this feature.

```
$ git config receive.advertisePushOptions true
```

After executing the above command inside the bare repository, I checked the contents of the config file and the content is this:

```
$ cat config
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = true
[receive]
    advertisePushOptions = true
```

The problem is that when trying to push using push options, I get this message:

```
$ git push staging-server --tags -o 'build-frontend'
fatal: the receiving end does not support push options
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

The version of git installed on the server is as follows (I cannot update):

```
$ git --version
git version 1.8.3.1
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a version of Git that doesn't support push options.  According to the history, Git push options came in around the 2.13 time frame.  If you want to use them, you'll need to use a newer Git.

As a note, since it looks like you're using CentOS 7, you may be able to use the Software Collections repository to find a newer Git.  But if you really can't upgrade, then you're out of luck.